# Showing that $TAx = \alpha Ax + x$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces

Let $T$ be a closed, distributive operator on a Banach space $X$, and let $\alpha$ be a fixed point of $\omega(T)$, where $\omega(T)=\mathbb{C}\setminus \sigma(T)$, i.e. $(\alpha1-T)^{-1}$ exists.

Now define $A=(T-\alpha1)^{-1}$, then $A$ is a one-to-one mapping of $X$ onto $D(T).$

I am now trying to see why the following two are true:

> 1. $TAx = \alpha Ax + x,$ for $x \in X$
> 2. $ATx=\alpha A x + x$, for $x \in D(T)$.

Can anybody please shown me why this is true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer for the first question

If $Ax=y$ it means that $x=Ty-\alpha y$ hence $Ty = x+\alpha y$ it follows that $TAx = \alpha Ax+x$.

Answer for the second question

As you said $A$ is one to one, in particular $B:=T-\alpha 1$ is also one to one so we can use it on both sides you have

$ATx=\alpha Ax+x$ if and only if $BATx=\alpha BAx+Bx$ but $B=A^{-1}$ so you have that $Tx=\alpha x + (T-\alpha 1 x)$ that is $Tx=T_x$.

So after applying $B$ to both sides you can the same value and $B$ is one to one it follows that $Tx = \alpha Ax+x$ (but $Tx$ is only defined for $x\in D(T)$ so this is why it's required).